# how to create a permalink for my page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a FAQ page with more than 60 questions in it, Now i want to create a link to each question, so that i can provide the link in my blog and and on clicking the users can directly land on that question instead of having to go through the whole FAQ page. So how can I create the link? I am using only html, css and javascript. So can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Research “anchor links”.

Answer (score 1):

You can use anchors.

Example from w3schools:

Add an id attribute to any  element:

```
<a id="tips">Useful Tips Section</a>
```

Then create a link to the  element (Useful Tips Section):

```
<a href="#tips">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>
```

Or, create a link to the  element (Useful Tips Section) from another page:

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html_links.htm#tips">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a contents section at the top of your FAQ page, which might have the questions ordered for example.

This can be achieved by creating an Ordered List, and listing your questions.

Then you can link your questions, so that when the person clicks on the question, he is directed to the exact location where the page is. This can be achieved using anchors, just like Yavor said.

You will first need to create an ID for each question, for example :

```
<div id="question1">Here is a question</div>
<div>Here is the answer to the question</div>
```

And then in the ordered menu, create an anchor to the corresponding question in your FAQ:

```
<ul><li><a href="#question1">This will take you to question 1</a></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the script below to scroll smoothly

```
<a href="#question1">1. How to log out?</a><br/>

<h3 id="question1">1. How to log out?</h3>
<p>Answer...</p>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top - 65
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```